# Surjective Endomorphism of Finitely Generated Modules.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, free-modules, flatness

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity. I would like to prove the following well-known result using a certain approach:

> Any surjective endomorphism of a finitely generated $A$-module $M$ is an isomorphism.

It suffices to prove it for local rings. For any surjection $\phi: M\to M$ the is an exact sequence $0\to \mathrm{Ker}(\phi)\to M\to M\to 0$. $\textbf{If we assume that}$ $M$ is flat over $A$, then $M\simeq A^n$ for some $n$ since $A$ is a local ring. We can tensor the exact sequence by the residue field $k=A/\mathfrak m$ to obtain another exact sequence $0\to \mathrm{Ker}(\phi)\otimes_A k\to k^n\to k^n\to 0$ and obtain that $\mathrm{Ker}(\phi)=0$. Since $M\simeq A^n$, $\mathrm{Ker}(\phi)$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module and thus by applying Nakayama's lemma one has $\mathrm{Ker}(\phi)=0$, as desired.

This works nicely by transforming the problem for a flat module over a local ring to a finite-dimensional vector space over the residue field $A/\mathfrak m$. One thing that bothers me is that this method does not naturally apply for an arbitary finitely generated module over a local ring $A$. First the kernel of the map $\phi: M\to M$ might not be finitely generated, and tensoring by the residue field only gives me the right exactness.

I would like to know if there is some technique or formalism to reduce the theorem for finitely generated modules over a local ring to finitely generated flat modules over the same ring. I should be most likely looking for a homological technique.

This question might be a little vague. Any help/reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to make it extra clear: you're not looking for a proof of the statement, but for a proof following that specific approach ? (or more generally a technique to reduce to flat modules)

Comment: @Max Yes I am looking for a proof using the approach I mentioned above. I know a proof using Nakayama's lemma by viewing $M$ as an $A[x]$-module through $\phi$ with surjectivity translating to $(x)M=M$. But I'd like to know the specific obstructions stopping us from using the approach I mentioned, and if possible, use some way to resolve the obstructions.

Comment: It's not true that a finitely generated flat module over a local ring must be free (you need finite presentation), and even submodules of $A^n$ don't need to be finitely generated. Basically, your argument only works if the ring is Noetherian, so I don't think it will generalize to prove the general statement